# ¿Cómo puedo desplegar una aplicación MERN si tengo dos carpetas separadas, una para el Frontend y otra para el Backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, git

En primer lugar, tengo dentro de una carpeta general dos carpetas, una que señala a Frontend en la cual he utilizado la herramienta create-react-app que al darle el comando 'npm run build' me genera la carpeta 'build' la cual contiene todo el código comprimido y estático, listo para pasarlo como archivo estático a mi servidor. En segundo lugar, en el Backend tengo mi archivo de servidor 'server.js':

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

//Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7000)

//Midlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

//Routes
app.use('/api/task', require('./routes/task.routes'))
app.use('/api/user', require('./routes/user.routes'))

//Static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build')))

module.exports = app
```

Entonces, ya que la carpeta Backend tiene conexión con la carpeta Frontend se me hace dificil entender si se puede subir estas dos carpetas, entiendo que es lo necesario para que mi app funcione. En todo caso que configuracion necesito al desplegarla, por ejemplo en Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizar los siguiente:

1. Desplegar tu servicio REST(*backend*) en Heroku. Al hacerlo te generara un enlace del servicio desplegado que puedes utilizar en tu *frontend*(que consumira el servicio).
2. Cambiar variables de entorno en el *frontend* a nivel local y verificar que funciona.
3. Desplegar *frontend* en Netlify/Vercel/Github Pages.

Espero haberte ayudado.